# ExactTarget: Unsubscribing from transactional vs marketing emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

ExactTarget question: If a customer unsubscribes from a triggered send email (triggered by an action they made on our website), does that unsubscribe them from ALL our emails, including marketing emails sent by list or data extension and other transactional or triggered send emails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really all depends on your unsubscribe process.  The default Marketing Cloud Profile Center page will unsubscribe the person at an All Subscriber level.  This means that all emails sent as "Commercial" Send Classification will not go to this person.  However, triggered emails usually should have the "Transactional" Send Classification set, with NO unsubscribe link included in the email(since there is no legal requirement to include an unsubscribe link in a transactional email).  So basically, if you set all your other triggered emails to transactional Send Classification, all people will receive them no matter their unsubscribe status.

Comment: Thank you. All of our triggered sends do have the transaction send classification set. However, they all include an unsubscribe link. I'm guessing the person that set this up originally either didn't know to not include it or was told by Compliance internally that they had to include it. Since our transactional emails do have an unsubscribe link, I'm guessing the recipient of the email will be unsubscribed from everything if they use that unsubscribe link in their transactional email.

Comment: Yes this is correct, they would then still receive transactional emails, but no other commercial emails - which is probably not what you would like to happen.  I would remove the unsubscribe link from all the transactional emails, just remember to republish the Triggered Send Definitions else the updates to the emails won't take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an auto-suppression configuration (which will require some build work and an automation) which can auto-suppress unsubscribed users in All Subscribers from Transactional Sends as well.